# Strange image stretch="none" behaviour

Tags: wpf

I have noticed some strange image display behaviour with stretch property set to "none"

For image which width > screen width & height > screen width, all area that is overlapping is clipped. (As expected)
Result: http://www.bildites.lv/images/urha41iqz8oz9hq8a6lu.png

For image which width > screen width & height < screen height, it's overlapping sides are clipped and it is centered vertically. (As expected)
Result: http://www.bildites.lv/images/kt4cc6jz0nogajyqmmc2.png

But for image which width < screen width & height > screen height, it get's resized to a thumbnail like size. (NOT as expected)
Result: http://www.bildites.lv/images/rqo9acdqg50lygndk4g.png

Here is a simple WPF app that demonstrates it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <Image Source="" Stretch="None"></Image>
</Grid>
```

Can someone please explain the third result?

Images I used for demonstration:
1) http://oi59.tinypic.com/2edqyis.jpg (it is resized, it was actually something like 4kx4k px)
2) http://www.bildites.lv/images/rjt4rl15g2ib7r74t77.jpg
3) http://www.bildites.lv/images/3f05cd42b2oqc1utmltt.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third image has its resolution set to 1000 DPI. You may change that to 96 DPI. See [here](https://superuser.com/q/607663).